# Cannot see what the "notation abuse" is, mentioned by author of book

Tags: reinforcement-learning, notation

From [Sutton and Barto, Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (second edition draft)](https://github.com/cinqs/RL-An-Introduction-Solutions/blob/master/Reinforcement%20Learning.pdf), in equation 3.4 of page 38.

> The probabilities given by the four-argument function p completely characterize the dynamics of a
>   finite MDP. From it, one can compute anything else one might want to know about the environment,
>   such as the state-transition probabilities (which we denote, with a slight abuse of notation, as a threeargument function
>
> $p(s^{'} | s, a) \dot{=}Pr\{S_t=s^{'} | S_{t-1} = s, A_{t-1}=a\} = 
> \sum_{r\in{R}}{p(s^{'},r|s,a)}$

The author mentioned, *with a slight abuse of notation*. 
where is the abuse in the notation please? I didn't see anything that is not proper.

Thank you.

Comment: @Neil Slater, saw the modification, and thank you. btw, do you have any thoughts on why the author said like that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand formal notation well enough to spot anything odd. Originally I thought this was about the combined iterator in the sum $\sum_{r,s'}$ which is a little unusual . . . but it's not that in the quoted section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical expression is completely legit. The abuse is in the fact that the function $p$, which is defined first time in equation 3.2, which:

> The function $p: S$ x $R$ x $S$ x $A \rightarrow [0,1]$. is an ordinary
>   deterministic function of four arguments...

is re-defined slightly differently just two lines after this definition (equation 3.4), as a three-argument function $p: S$ x $S$ x $A \rightarrow [0,1]$.

If they used $p$ to represent the regular probability measure, there would be no abuse. In the authors' notation, $p$ is a deterministic function, while the regular probability function is denoted as $Pr$; and keeping the same name for slightly different functions, is where the "innocent" notation abuse comes from.

Comment: this makes sense, but I want to wait to see is there more thought on this, and I notice one guy who is the author's apprentice, and I think he may help. and Thanks